# Spring Boot Is it possible to use an interface as controller parameter and let spring use it's implementation to instantiate it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    fun findSomething(params: MyInterface) {
        when (params) {
            is FirstImplementation -> doSomeThing()
            is SecondImplementation -> doSomeThing()
        }
    } 
}

sealed interface MyInterface

class FirstImplementation(
    val a: String,
    val b: Int,
) : MyInterface

class SecondImplementation(
    val b: Int,
    val c: String,
) : MyInterface
```

i tried like this, but i got an auto generated aop proxy of the interface, so failed at when expression..

Comment: You’re going to need some Jackson annotations.

Comment: You might be able to hack this together with a @jsonCreator factory method on MyInterface taking nullable a,c and non nullable b and then instantiate the right class based on what you got. But I'm not sure how spring/jackson play together with kotlin nullability in that situation. Alternatively you can always just get a map of params and then just implement the mapping yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when defining a controller in Spring MVC, we decorate its methods with various annotations that specify the request: the URL of the endpoint, the HTTP request method, the path variables, and so on.

If we add web request annotations to the controller, they'll take precedence over the interface's ones. In other words, Spring interprets the controller interfaces in a way similar to how Java deals with inheritance.

for further info please refer to this blog post
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-interface-driven-controllers